# Sound of water running after bath taps turned off

Tags: water, leak, bathtub, drain-waste-vent

When running a bath, for the duration of my bath I hear water running/heavy trickling coming from the drain away holes at the top of the bath drain.

This has got louder and stronger over the last few weeks.
The plug is not leaking so don't know what is causing this sound.

Is it a leak or big problem?

Answer (score 1):

If the tub doesn't have a P-trap, or the P-trap is being emptied (by a nearby toilet flush or washing machine drain pump) due to a venting issue, you might be hearing water running elsewhere in the drain system, possibly even the main sewer line.